# Compare 2 Results<CustomObject> by object of selected index of filteredList swift4

Tags: arrays, swift

I have 2 lists of same custom object i.e. News

```
class News: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String?
    @objc dynamic var date: Date?
    @objc dynamic var contentUrl: String?
}
```

and 2 lists are

```
var filteredList: Results<News>! = nil
var newsList: Results<News> {
    get {
        return realm.objects(News.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: 
false)
    }
}
```

I am filtering the list and the filtered data is storing in `filteredList`. 
Now I want to send the `IndexPath` of `newsList` to the next VC.  When I search in the list, filteredList is appending to the tableView which is absolutely correct. When I selecting row from filteredList it is giving index of filteredList. Now though user selects filteredList's index , it should compare with the object of `newList` and should return that indexPath /index of `newsList`

I have done it by my own way

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {
    searchController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    var sendIndex : IndexPath?
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    if !searchBarIsEmpty(){
        for (index,news) in newsList.enumerated(){
            if news.title == filteredList[indexPath.row].title{
                sendIndex = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            }
        }
    }else{
        sendIndex = indexPath
    }
    if let index = sendIndex{
        let vc = NewsDetailsVC(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        vc.tappedIndex = index
        vc.title = "News Details"
        vc.isSelectNews = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}
```

but it can be more optimise.. Please suggest some logic of optimisation

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: When I selecting row from filteredList it is giving index of filteredList. Now though user selects filteredList's index , it should compare with the object of newList and should return that indexPath /index of newsList

Comment: Show us the code which gives you the index from the filtered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *one-liner* for finding the index to be sent.

```
if !searchBarIsEmpty() {
    sendIndex = IndexPath(row: newsList.firstIndex(where: { $0.title == filteredList[indexPath.row].title }), section: 0)
}
```

**Note:** `title` is assumed to be the primary key. Compare with the appropriate primary key.